# Get Rid with Duplicate Dialog Nodes Watson Conversation

Tags: dialog, nodes, watson-conversation

I am trying to build a Watson Conversation for an application. I have created a single **intent** and it has **multiple child dialog nodes**. I am having **two sibling dialog nodes** having **same child nodes** and the hierarchy would be repeated.

So, is there any way to handle this situation? (*I mean to reduce duplicate nodes or to reuse the existing nodes.*) Because it repeats the nodes multiple times for each sibling dialog nodes.

**Below image is self-explanatory.**

[image]

When you look at the image below, you see there are **two dialog nodes are similar** for both **siblings nodes**`(@boolean:yes / @boolean:no)`.

So, Without creating two similar nodes, how can I create a common node which will be used by both siblings?

Any help, please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your issue you can use a continue from and point it to the input node prior to where you want to continue on with the tree.

[image]